# In what ways can I speed up my Azure SQL Server Queries

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using MS Azure to host a SQL Server database. And SQL Server is something that I am still a complete novice at.

In that database, I have a few million records. I can search fairly quickly on the primary key but some of my indexed columns are taking around 4:30+ to perform a query.

For example I will have a query of

```
Select Top 100 *
from Ticket__c
where Contact__c = 'a191a00000134mcAAA'
```

The `Contact__c` column is indexed / non-clustered. Not sure if I set this up with the best option.

Are there simple things that I should be looking at in order to improve performance. i.e. should I be indexing differently. Do I need to run some sort of indexing function regularly? etc...

All tips appreciated for where I should look to work to make the database queries perform better.

Comment: You may try adding an index to the `Contact__c`column.  But, more important than this, you are using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` clause.  This does not make much sense, because you haven't told SQL Server _which_ top 100 records you want.  Add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

Comment: do you really need to retrieve *all* columns?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need to regularly maintain existing indexes and update statistics as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/). Azure Automation (runbooks) can help automating these tasks.

Azure can also help you by creating automatically other indexes your queries may need. For this you may need to enable [automatic tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning-enable).

Azure also gives you performance recommendations. Please apply them if they exist as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning-enable).

Answer (score 0):

For a query to perform well, you will need to remember

1.It should be indexed
2.Server should not be facing any of CPU,IO,RAM pressure

For your given query, if your query is non clustered, you should include all columns in your query.

Further use below query to see if your DTU is consistently averaging above 90% for a period of time..If this is the case, you should upgrade your tier or tune queries based on metric

```
SELECT  
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU use in percent',
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU use in percent',
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average data I/O in percent',
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum data I/O in percent',
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average log write use in percent',
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum log write use in percent',
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average memory use in percent',
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum memory use in percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```